# Powershell formatting into table with no dots

Tags: powershell

I would like to format the output into a table with no dots. I tried this code but it does not seem to work.

```
Get-AzureDisk | where { $_.AttachedTo -eq $null } | Format-Table diskname, medialink, DiskSizeInGB -AutoSize| Out-File C:\Temp\unuseddisk.txt
```

what else do i need to do?

Comment: What do you mean by "no dots"? What does the output look like? Can you post it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
Get-AzureDisk |
   where { $_.AttachedTo -eq $null } |
       Format-Table diskname, medialink, DiskSizeInGB -AutoSize | 
         out-string -width 4096 | Out-File C:\Temp\unuseddisk.txt
```